# .NET Core gives unknown error while processing HTTPS certificate

Tags: ssl, .net-core, ssl-certificate, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to build a .NET Core server that uses a HTTPS connection.

I created a self-signed certificate using `dotnet dev-certs` tool and
set up Kestrel like this:

```
    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseKestrel(options =>
                    {
                        options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000, lisOpt => lisOpt.UseHttps("myCert.pfx", "test"));
                    })
                  .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
```

But when I try to connect to it with my client, I keep getting this exception:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Uncaught exception from the OnConnectionAsync method of an IConnectionAdapter.
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsServerAsync>b__50_2(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionAdapter.InnerOnConnectionAsync(ConnectionAdapterContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.FrameConnection.ApplyConnectionAdaptersAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Uncaught exception from the OnConnectionAsync method of an IConnectionAdapter.
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try ```dotnet dev-certs https --trust```?

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Yes, I did...

Comment: That might happen when your dev-certs expire
`dotnet dev-certs https --trust` alone won't help, you'll need to remove them first by `dotnet dev-certs https --clean`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This apparently happened because my client sent requests to 127.0.0.1 instead of 'localhost'.

Comment: `dotnet dev-certs https --verbose` will show the CN (which is `localhost`) among other info